# loading directive with attributes to page as object from a Controller generates an error

Tags: angularjs

I am having an issue with an application I am working on.  In my app I have a module that has a number of costom directives.  On one of my pages I have a controller that I am using and in this controller I am adding a call to one of my directives to the page as a new element by creating a var to hold the compiled code and then appending it to the page.  The code below is working perfectly.

```
var compiledeHTML = $compile("<repoertcountrycompare></repoertcountrycompare>")($scope); 
$(ReportToLoad).append(compiledeHTML);
```

Where I am having an issue is when I need to add directive that has attributes that I need to set. In the code below I am trying to add a directive called TableauReport to the page with three attributes.

```
var compiledeHTML = $compile("<tableau-report rname='Consumer-Brand' countrystr='United States' reportqtr='2016 Q1'></tableau-report>")($scope);
$(ReportToLoad).append(compiledeHTML);
```

I have tested the directive by including the tag on the page and it works perfectly with these attributes but when I use the code below to add it to the page from the controller I get the following errors:

> arguments = Accessing the 'arguments' property of a function is not
>   allowed in strict mode
>
> caller = Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments
>   object is not allowed in strict mode

Has anyone else ran into this kind of issue before and know how to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.  I needed to use @ in my Directive rather than = for the attributes I was passing to the directive.